# WordPress Footer Hook, PHP Editing Error

Tags: php, wordpress

How can i edit this to just print out Copyright © 2017. All Rights Reserved. I keep getting an error on the last curly bracket when the second part of the function is removed and i can't figure it out.

```
 */
function nepalbuzz_get_content() {
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();

    return sprintf( _x( 'Copyright &copy; %1$s %2$s. All Rights Reserved', '1: Year, 2: Site Title with home URL', 'nepalbuzz' ), date_i18n( __( 'Y', 'nepalbuzz' ) ), '<a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">'. esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '</a>'  ) . ' &#124; ' . $theme_data->get( 'Name') . '&nbsp;' . esc_html__( 'by', 'nepalbuzz' ). '&nbsp;<a target="_blank" href="'. $theme_data->get( 'AuthorURI' ) .'">'. $theme_data->get( 'Author' ) .'</a>';
}
```

I have edited to this:

```
function nepalbuzz_get_content() {
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();

    return sprintf( _x( 'Copyright &copy; %1$s %2$s. All Rights Reserved', '1: Year, 2: Site Title with home URL', 'nepalbuzz' ), date_i18n( __( 'Y', 'nepalbuzz' ) ), '<a href="'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'">'. esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '</a>'  ) ; }
```

But I am still getting an unexpected syntax. Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code that  registers the footer hook?

Comment: `code`function nepalbuzz_footer_content() {
 //nepalbuzz_flush_transients();
 if ( !$output = get_transient( 'nepalbuzz_footer_content' ) ) {
  $output =  '<div id="footer-content" class="copyright">' . nepalbuzz_get_content() . '</div>';

     set_transient( 'nepalbuzz_footer_content', $output, 86940 );
    }

    echo $output;
}
add_action( 'nepalbuzz_footer', 'nepalbuzz_footer_content', 50 );`code`

Comment: if ( ! function_exists( 'nepalbuzz_site_generator_end' ) ) :
 /**
  * Start Header id #masthead and class .wrapper
  *
  * @since NepalBuzz 0.1
  *
  */
 function nepalbuzz_site_generator_end() {
  ?>
   </div><!-- .wrapper -->
  </div><!-- #site-generator -->
  <?php
 }
endif;
add_action( 'nepalbuzz_footer', 'nepalbuzz_site_generator_end', 60 );

Answer (score 0):

You may just need to escape your double quotes.

```
function nepalbuzz_get_content() {
    $theme_data = wp_get_theme();

    return sprintf( _x( 'Copyright &copy; %1$s %2$s. All Rights Reserved', '1: Year, 2: Site Title with home URL', 'nepalbuzz' ), date_i18n( __( 'Y', 'nepalbuzz' ) ), '<a href=\"'. esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) .'\">'. esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ) . '</a>'  ) ; }
```

Comment: Thank you John, this solved my issue! I really appreciate your help.